# Evaluate a polynomial at a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, polynomials

I have a polynomial and a matrix, say `z^3 + z + 1` and `{{1,1,1},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}`.  I can use this code:

```
T = {{1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}; 
T.T.T + T + IdentityMatrix[3]
```

> ```
> {{3, 2, 2}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}
> ```

But for polynomials with many terms it becomes tedious to write out the polynomial in terms of matrix products.  Is there an automated way to evaluate a polynomial at a matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "ReplaceAll" to replace the symbol in your polynomial by a matrix.  But you must also take care to replace "1" by the IdentityMatrix. E.g.:

```
z^3 + z + 1 /. {1 -> IdentityMatrix[3], z -> {{1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}} }

(* {{3, 2, 2}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}} *)
```

Comment: Please note that this applies the powers to each matrix element separately, rather than computing the dot product/matrix power

Comment: Agreed with Lukas.  Should easily be fixed by first doing a `/. Power -> MatrixPower`.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious solution here, of course, is to use `MatrixFunction[]`:

```
MatrixFunction[Function[z, z^3 + z + 1], {{1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}]
   {{3, 2, 2}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}
```

Answer (score 2):

- At first we  extract the coefficient from the polynomial `f[z]`.
- And them we construct a matrix form of `f[m]` where `m` is a matrix. For `i>=1`, we use `MatrixPower[m,i]` or `Dot @@ ConstantArray[m, i]`,but for `i==0` we use `IdentityMatrix` since `m` maybe singular.

```
Clear[f, m, coef];
f[z_] = z^3 + z + 1;
m = {{1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};
coef = CoefficientList[f[z], z]
coef . Prepend[Table[MatrixPower[m, i], {i, 1, Length[coef] - 1}], 
  IdentityMatrix[Dimensions[m] // First]]
1*IdentityMatrix[3] + 1*m + 0*m . m + 1*m . m . m
```

[image]

- Test another polynomial and another matrix. It indicate that the method by using `ReplaceAll` is wrong.

```
Clear[f, m, coef];
f[z_] = 2 z^3 + 3*z^2 + 4 z + 5;
m = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}};
coef = CoefficientList[f[z], z]
coef . Prepend[Table[MatrixPower[m, i], {i, 1, Length[coef] - 1}], 
  IdentityMatrix[Dimensions[m] // First]]
5*IdentityMatrix[3] + 4*m + 3*m . m + 2*m . m . m
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could overload some operators use https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html

```
ClearAll[mat];
mat /: mat[x_] ^ n_ := mat[MatrixPower[x,n]];
mat /: mat[x_] + n_?NumericQ := mat[x + IdentityMatrix[Dimensions[x] // First] * n];
mat /: mat[x_] + mat[y_] := mat[x + y];
z = mat[{{1,1,1},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}];
z^3 + z + 1
```

> ```
> mat[{{3, 2, 2}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]
> ```